# Foreach итерирует объект по нескольку раз

Tags: c#, unity3d, linq, foreach

Столкнулся с проблемой во время вставления значений в поля. При работе скриптов ниже, когда в коде для персонажа я вызываю дебаг лог, чтобы вывести сообщение в unity, я получаю "0 and 0", что значит, что все поля сбросились по какой то причине. Я проверил отладкой, и да, они действительно сбрасываются после какого то события. К тому же оказалось, что итерируются эти две "foreach" по нескольку раз, и каждую итерацию значения сбрасываются.

Мои вопросы такие: 1.Почему они сбрасываются? 2. Как сделать итерацию разовой, а не несколько раз? 3.Действительно ли при каждой итерации поля в "foreach" сбрасываются, или что то другое?

XML файл для монстра:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Stats>
    <EStats>
        <Name>"Monster"</Name>
        <Health>10</Health>
        <Strength>2</Strength>
    </EStats>
</Stats>
```

Код с монстром:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

namespace DarkestBone
{
    public class Monster_Stats : MonoBehaviour
    {

        public string Monster_Name;
        public int Monster_Health;
        public int Monster_Strength;

        void Start()
        {
            XDocument Xdoc = XDocument.Load("D:\\unity projects\\DarkestBone\\Assets\\Monster_Stats.xml");
            XElement Stats = Xdoc.Element("Stats");
            
                foreach (XElement EStats in Stats.Elements("EStats"))
                {
                    XElement Name = EStats.Element("Name");
                    XElement HP = EStats.Element("Health");
                    XElement STR = EStats.Element("Strength");
                    string Monster_Name = Name.Value;
                    int.TryParse(HP.Value, out Monster_Health);
                    int.TryParse(STR.Value, out Monster_Strength);
                    
                }
            
            
        }

        
        void Update()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

XML файл для персонажа:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Stats>
        <EStats>
            <Name>"Mendzek"</Name>
            <Health>10</Health>
            <Willpower>5</Willpower>
            <Body>5</Body>
            <Strength>3</Strength>
            <Speed>2</Speed>
            <Skill>1</Skill>
            <Intuition>1</Intuition>
            <Faith>8</Faith>
        </EStats>
</Stats>
```

Код с персонажем:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace DarkestBone {
    public class MC_Stats : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject MC;
        Monster_Stats Monster_Stats = new Monster_Stats();



        public string MC_Name;
        public int MC_Health;
        public int MC_Willpower;
        public int MC_Body;
        public int MC_Strength;
        public int MC_Speed;
        public int MC_Skill;
        public int MC_Intuition;
        public int MC_Faith;
            

        public void Start()
    {

        XDocument Xdoc = XDocument.Load("D:\\unity projects\\DarkestBone\\Assets\\MC_Stats.xml");
        XElement Stats = Xdoc.Element("Stats");
        foreach (XElement EStats in Stats.Elements("EStats"))
        {
   

            XElement Name = EStats.Element("Name");
            XElement HP = EStats.Element("Health");
            XElement WIL = EStats.Element("Willpower");
            XElement BDY = EStats.Element("Body");
            XElement STR = EStats.Element("Strength");
            XElement SPD = EStats.Element("Speed");
            XElement SKL = EStats.Element("Skill");
            XElement INT = EStats.Element("Intuition");
            XElement FTH = EStats.Element("Faith");
            MC_Name = Name.Value;
            int.TryParse(HP.Value, out MC_Health);
            int.TryParse(STR.Value, out MC_Strength);
            int.TryParse(WIL.Value, out MC_Willpower);
            int.TryParse(BDY.Value, out MC_Body);
            int.TryParse(SPD.Value, out MC_Speed);
            int.TryParse(SKL.Value, out MC_Skill);
            int.TryParse(INT.Value, out MC_Intuition);
            int.TryParse(FTH.Value, out MC_Faith);
        }

    }
    public void Attack()
    {
             Monster_Stats.Monster_Health = Monster_Stats.Monster_Health - MC_Strength;
             Debug.Log($" {MC_Name} attacking {Monster_Stats.name} and deal {MC_Strength} damage. {Monster_Stats.Monster_Name} have {Monster_Stats.Monster_Health} HP now.");
                Debug.Log($"{MC_Strength} and {Monster_Stats.Monster_Strength}"); //выводит "0 and 0", хотя не должно
            
    }
    
    public void Update()
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: `while (check <= 1)` что это?

Comment: уже исправил, этого нет сейчас в коде

Comment: У монстра в цикле используется не **поле** класса, а **локальная** переменная: `string Monster_Name = Name.Value;`. Учитывая это, а также наличие какого-то ненужного цикла `while` в первой версии вопроса, дело наверняка в подобных ошибках и опечатках. Ищите их внимательней или публикуйте **реальный** код.

Comment: Правильно используя возможности `XElement`, можно вместо `TryParse` писать кратко: `Monster_Strength = (int)STR;`. Или ещё проще: `Monster_Strength = (int)EStats.Element("Strength");`

Comment: Так, значит, я полагаю, что вместо создания переменной внутри цикла я создам ее в начале кода с модификатором public, и тогда с этой переменной все будет в порядке, но с другими что? Насчет реального кода, это актуальный код, новее некуда

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том, что я при выводе результатов в Debug.Log использовал значения из объекта класса монстра и главного героя, то есть тех, что я создал в начале MC_Stats. Все значения таким образом равны нулю. Для исправления проблемы я на всех переменных установил модификатор static.